# Adding specific dictionary fields if condition applies

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a 2 lists of dictionaries in python (2.7) and I want to update each dictionary in the list if condition applies.

Example:

```
first= 
[
    {'name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'age':'27'},
    {'name': 'Jack', 'last_name': 'Sparrow', 'age':'26'}
]
second = 
[
    {'full_name': 'John Doe', 'height':130},
    {'full_name': 'Donkey Kong', 'height':156},
    {'full_name': 'Jack Sparrow', 'height':180}
]
```

Now I want to update the first dict if name + last_name equals full_name, and add the height parameter to it.

This works just fine, but it is very ugly, and also not so nice looking if I have ten fields like 'height' to add:

```
 for i in first:
    for k in second:
        if (i['name'] + ' ' + i['last_name'] == k['full_name']):
            i['height'] = k['height']
```

Any nice way to do it in the "Pythonic" way?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you using the second dict for anything else?

Comment: Nope, can change it as much as I want

Comment: And I was thinking along the lines of @jpp's answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restructure your second list of dictionaries into a single dictionary:

```
second_dict = {i['full_name']: i['height'] for i in second}
```

Then use a `for` loop:

```
for item in first:
    key = item['name'] + ' ' + item['last_name']
    if key in second_dict:
        item['height'] = second_dict[key]
```

Result:

```
print(first)

[{'age': '27', 'height': 130, 'last_name': 'Doe', 'name': 'John'},
 {'age': '26', 'height': 180, 'last_name': 'Sparrow', 'name': 'Jack'}]
```